# The characteristic polynomial of the product of two linear recurrences

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, recurrences

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and let $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}$, $(b_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be two linear recurrences with terms in $\mathbb{F}$ and respective characteristic polynomials $f(X), g(X) \in \mathbb{F}[X]$.
Put $c_n := a_n b_n$ for all integers $n \geq 0$. 
It is well-known than $(c_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is a linear recurrence.

Answering [ME question 1348838](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348838/sum-and-product-of-linear-recurrences), Julian Rosen claimed (and proved) that a characteristic polynomial for $(c_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is given by $h(x) := \operatorname{Res}_Y(f(Y), Y^{\deg(g)}g(X/Y))$, where $\operatorname{Res}_Y$ is the resultant respect to $Y$. In truth, the proof was given for $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$, but no step refers to particular properties of the complex numbers, so the claim holds in any field.

Looking on the classic book on linear recurrences [1], I could not find Rosen's result. Neither I found it in [2] (for linear recurrences on finite fields).

**Does someone have a reference for it?**

Thank you very much.

[1] *G. Everest, A. van der Poorten, I. E. Shparlinski, and T. Ward - Recurrence Sequences*

[2] *R. Lidl and H. Niederreiter - Introduction to Finite Fields and Their Applications*

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a little late, but I was looking exactly for this and Theorem 4.1 in the book by [Everest et al.](https://books.google.de/books?id=VgE-CgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA65#v=onepage&q&f=false) (reference [1](https://books.google.de/books?id=VgE-CgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA65#v=onepage&q&f=false) you cite, page 65) proves precisely this.

Comment: No, it doesn't prove that $h(x)$ is a characteristic polynomial for $(c_n)_{n \geq 0}$.

Comment: oops. yes, you're right. I misunderstood your question!